# Могу ли я опубликовать приложение в Google Play не сразу после проверки?

Tags: google-play, release-management

Могу ли я опубликовать приложение в `Google Play` не сразу после проверки приложения?
Мне в компании достался чужой проект, из которого ушел разработчик. Там была череда правок и релизов, т.е., это не первый релиз. Я ни разу не релизил приложения в прод. И у меня вопрос: после того, как я нажму кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Rollout" мое приложение отправится на проверку и сразу после проврки оно станет доступно в `Play Market`? Или я могу потом сам, вручную после проверки, сделать доступной новую версию в `Play Market`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переключателя для отложенной публикации похоже, что нет

Comment: внизу должен быть свитч "отложенная публикация". он как раз сделает то, что хотите - проверка будет пройдена, но когда опубликовать - решаете сами.

Comment: Странно, этот свитч должен быть на этой же странице? Не вижу его. 

UPD: прикерпил к вопросу скрин

Comment: Судя по всему, эту опцию нужно включить в настройках. Publishing overview -> Managed publishing status

Comment: а там где 100 в опциях есть 0?

Comment: в каких опциях? там поле для ручного ввода